# How do I maximize the display screen in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Python programming and I recently started working with the PyGame module. Here is a simple piece of code to initialize a display screen. My question is : Currently, the maximize button is disabled and I cannot resize the screen. How do I enable it to switch between full screen and back?
Thanks

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Create a displace surface object
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

mainLoop = True

while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To become fullscreen at native resolution, do

```
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

To make the window resizeable, add the `pygame.RESIZABLE` parameter when seting the mode. You can set the mode of the screen surface multiple times but you might have to do `pygame.display.quit()` followed by `pygame.display.init()`

You should also check the pygame documentation here http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode

Answer (score 12):

The method you are looking for is [`pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen)

Or, as the guide recommends in most situations, calling [`pygame.display.set_mode()` with the `FULLSCREEN` tag](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

In your case this would look like

```
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

(Please use the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` instead of just `FULLSCREEN` because upon testing with my own system `FULLSCREEN` just maximized the window without fitting the resolution while `pygame.FULLSCREEN` fit my resolution as well as maximizing.)

Comment: What would "just `FULLSCREEN`" mean?

Answer (score 5):

```
import pygame, os

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1' # You have to call this before pygame.init()

pygame.init()

info = pygame.display.Info() # You have to call this before pygame.display.set_mode()
screen_width,screen_height = info.current_w,info.current_h
```

These are the dimensions of your screen/monitor. You can use these or reduce them to exclude borders and title bar:

```
window_width,window_height = screen_width-10,screen_height-50
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width,window_height))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 4):

This will let you toggle from maximize to the initial size

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Create a displace surface object
#Below line will let you toggle from maximize to the initial size
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), RESIZABLE)

mainLoop = True

while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to add the full screen parameter onto the display declaration like this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Create a displace surface object
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), FULLSCREEN)

mainLoop = True

while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: how do I exit the fullscreen plot?