# Which screen size in Pygame for an 3.5 inch LCD?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, screen

I try to fill out my whole LCD screen in Pygame with the best sharp resolution possible. So there is a difference between computer screen and the LCD.

My LCD has resolution is 480×320. So choosing this resolution numbers would be the best solution?

Currently I fill the screen with this code:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
```

But the Pygame screen on Raspberry Pi only displays certain parts of the of the screen I had on computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I maximize the display screen in PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538506/how-do-i-maximize-the-display-screen-in-pygame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want fullscreen, just add:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_F]:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480),FULLSCREEN)
elif keys[pygame.K_M]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
```

so if you press 'F', the screen becomes fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks, but why you kept the first 2 parameters in `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480),FULLSCREEN)`? Are they needed if you turn to fullscreen anyway?