# How to make a Pygame Zero window full screen?

Tags: python, pygame, pgzero

I am using the easy-to-use Python library pgzero (which uses `pygame` internally) for programming games.

How can I make the game window full screen?

```
import pgzrun

TITLE = "Hello World"

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600

pgzrun.go()
```

Note: I am using the runtime helper lib pgzrun to make the game executable without an OS shell command... It implicitly imports the pgzero lib...

Edit: pgzero uses pygame internally, perhaps there is a change the window mode using the `pygame` API...

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538506/how-do-i-maximize-the-display-screen-in-pygame

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN The question is how to do it with [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the pygame surface which represents the game screen by [`screen.surface`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#screen) and you can change the surface in [`draw()`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html) by [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). e.g.:

```py
import pgzrun
import pygame

TITLE = "Hello World"

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600

def draw():
    screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pgzrun.go()
```

Or switch to fullscreen when the <kbd>f</kbd> key is pressed respectively return to window mode when the <kbd>w</kbd> key is pressed in the key down event (`on_key_down`):

```py
import pgzrun
import pygame

TITLE = "Hello World"

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600

def on_key_down(key):
    if key == keys.F:
        screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    elif key == keys.W:
        screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: Great answer :-) I forgot to ask how to escape from the black screen I get now after running the code. What is the default mode (I would add a key handler then to end the "game" and seeing the normal desktop again)...

Comment: @RYoda you can use `on_key_down` to switch between fullscreen and window mode. I've extended the answer.

Comment: @RYoda Ctrl-Q will always quit in any Pygame Zero game (might be Cmd-Q on Mac).

Comment: The first example above (without the key handling) is very flashy, but if you only set screen.surface the first time draw() is called, it works great!

Answer (score -2):

```
import pgzrun
import pygame

TITLE = "Hello World"

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600

def draw():
    screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you please explain your answer a little bit more since it looks it contains exactly the same code of the already accepted answer by Rabbid76? THX!